# PHP shell_exec command with variable

Tags: php, var

The following takes a string and checks all files on the server (./*) to see if said string exists in any files, then outputs the data to > grep_results.txt:

```
$command = 'grep -ri "any string goes here" ./* > grep_results.txt';
shell_exec($command);
```

Anyway, if possible I would like to pass it a variable submitted by the following html form:

```
        <form id='searchform' action='/GREP.php' method='post'>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <input type='text' name='SearchString' placeholder='Search string...'>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Find' class='button'>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I started off doing this:

```
$string = $_POST['SearchString'];
echo $string;
```

And, of course, any string submitted is echoed back.

The place where I'm stuck is, I tried this out and it didn't work:

```
$string = $_POST['SearchString'];
$command = 'grep -ri "'.$string.'" ./* > grep_results.txt';
shell_exec($command);
```

How do I pass $string to $command?

Comment: The code at the top (with the hard-coded string) does work correctly already when you call it from the browser? `grep_results.txt` must be writable by the web server user for this to work, and you _absolutely must_ call `escapeshellarg()` on `$string` before passing it to `$command`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

To Michael Berkowski (in comments), thank you, escapeshellarg did the trick.

The working code is now:

```
$string = $_POST['SearchString'];

$searchstring = escapeshellarg($string);

$command = 'grep -ri "'.$searchstring.'" ./* > grep_results.txt';

shell_exec($command);
```